# Edit form rendered blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My model/id/edit form is rendered blank, without rendering the values that are already in the database. I don't see this is the regular behaviour in a brand new rails app.

Any insights what's blocking those values to be rendered in the form?

Rails 6.1.4
ruby 2.7.3p183

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: task) do |form| %>
  <%= render "shared/error_messages", resource: form.object %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title, class: "form-control", prepopulated: "true", :value => params[:title] %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.rich_text_area :description, data: { controller: "mentions", mentions_target: "field" }, class: "form-control", :value => params[:description] %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :credits %>
    <%= form.number_field :credits, class: "form-control", :value => params[:credits] %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :category %>
    <%= form.select :category,  [ 'Development', 'Design' ], class: "form-control", :value => params[:category] %>
  </div>

  <% if current_user.admin === true %>
    <%= form.collection_check_boxes(:user_ids, User.where(id: 1).all, :id, :name) do |u| %>
      <%= u.label(class: "check_box") { u.check_box(checked: true, class: "add_margin") + u.text } %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="flex justify-between form-group">
    <%= form.button class: "btn btn-primary" %>

    <% if form.object.persisted? %>
      <%= link_to t("delete"), form.object, class: "btn btn-danger outline", method: :delete, data: { confirm: t("are_you_sure") } %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :load_entities, only: :show

  # GET /tasks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1 or /tasks/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: "Task was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_task
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    puts @task
    puts @task.id
  end

  # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description, :credits, :deliverydate, :submitteddate, :createdby, :default, :status, :category, :assignedto, user_ids: [])
  end

end
```

Edit:
Adding trace for set_task , example when opening the Edit form for Task ID 7

```
10:30:24 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:91:in `set_task'
10:30:24 web.1     | #<Task:0x000000010d75ddf8>
10:30:24 web.1     | 7
10:30:24 web.1     |   Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
```

Comment: where are you rendering the form ?

Comment: Is the Task being found? Add `puts @task` in the `set_task` action.

Comment: @JuxSalley Form is just rendered in its own view /tasks/1/edit

Comment: @BSeven Yes, it's correctly tracked - I updated the post to show the trace too

Comment: One thing to check is that you don't have an explicit `edit` method in your controller. What happens if you add one (even a blank one)? You have a `before_action` set but, if you don't actually have the method defined, this may not be running. Also, what happens if you render the values you expect to see on the page, outside the form (with e.g. `<%= @task.title %>`)? If the values don't render, that tells you the variable isn't set for some reason.

Comment: @JohnP Yea, I have an edit method, I didn't include initially because it is empty. But it's there. I just updated the post to show it now. task.title is correctly rendered in the edit view (out of the form itself)

Comment: OK, so you define a variable `@task` but use `task` in your `form_with` declaration. Is this a typo? Because it should be `@task`.

Comment: @JohnP Just tried that, it didn't fix it.

Comment: OK, so what I'd do next is look at exactly what HTML is output by the `form_with` helper as you have it configured, and try to see where it's going wrong. Is it not finding the record, is it not finding the fields, is it something else? (I assume that you mean by "rendered blank" in the question that the form exists but there are no values in the fields, rather than that the form doesn't exist at all?) I'd also start using the byebug or better_errors gems to add breakpoints and check the code execution.

Comment: (PS Also, your trace above doesn't show the layout you indicate being rendered, just application.html.erb, so I'd also check your routes and add some text on-page to make sure it's actually rendering the HTML page you think it is!)